# Git pulling onto a vm without an ssh key

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine

I'm trying to pull an existing github repo made on my local machine onto a vm running on EC2 that will be used by multiple people. I have some concerns with using an ssh key without a password, so I was wondering if there was any way to pull directly onto the VM either anonymously, or by providing the username and password of the account that originally pushed the repo, so that my personal information won't have to be stored on the vm, and there's no security risk in having someone get ahold of a password-less ssh key for the vm. Is this possible?

Currently running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Is your git repo from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend generating a new key and adding it as deployment key to your specific repo.
These keys are linked to a specific repo, not your account.

Alot of options are also available here.

https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys